# How to modify the coordinate line width in Julia's Makie drawings

Tags: julia

How to modify the coordinate line width in Julia's(1.8.5) Makie drawings.
Just like this:

[image: 1]

I can't find the attribute setting of the relevant coordinate line width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makie calls the axis borders "spines." The appropriate Axis parameter that changes the width of the spine is called [`spinewidth`](https://docs.makie.org/stable/api/#Axis), and is documented in the API (but is not mentioned in the tutorial):

```
using CairoMakie
f = Figure(resolution = (200, 100))
Axis(f[1, 1])
Axis(f[1, 2], spinewidth = 4.5)
```

[image: Two empty axes side by side; the one on the left has a thin border, and the one on the right has a thick border]

Unlike other spine parameters (e.g., `bottomspinecolor`, `leftspinevisible`, etc.), you cannot separately change the width of the spines on the different sides of the axis: it's all or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If by "coordinate line width" you mean the length of the little tick which indicates coordinate position, then you can change this by `xticksize` and `yticksize`.  If you want to make them thicker, it's `xtickwidth` and `ytickwidth`.